# Как заставить куб вращаться по оси?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Если менять у `.page` свойство `transform`, то есть изменять `deg`, то блок вращается вокруг своего ребра, можно ли сделать так, чтобы он вращался относительно центра?

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.page {
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  transform-origin: center center;
  margin: 100px;
  margin-left: 400px;
  position: relative;
  transform: rotateX(20deg);
  perspective: 800px;
}


.slide {
  position: absolute;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: 40px;
  color: #c8d6e5;
}

.slide:nth-child(1) {
  background-color: #1dd1a1;
  transform: translateZ(150px);
}

.slide:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: #feca57;
  transform: rotateX(90deg) translateZ(150px);
}

.slide:nth-child(3) {
  background-color: #ff6b6b;
  transform: rotateX(-90deg) translateZ(150px);
}

.slide:nth-child(4) {
  background-color: #48dbfb;
  transform: rotateY(180deg) translateZ(150px);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="page">
    <div class="slide">
      We are creative
    </div>
    <div class="slide">
      We are cool
    </div>
    <div class="slide">
      We are mazing
    </div>
    <div class="slide">
      We are super
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

Вот куб который я делал давно, может поможет разобраться (заменил цветовую гамму и текст на сторонах куба, согласно показанному шаблону):

```js
$(function(){
            $(document).mousemove(function(e){
              $('.cube').css({
               'transform':'rotateX('+e.pageY+'deg) rotateY('+e.pageX+'deg)'
        })
   });
});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  margin: 200px auto;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  perspective: 3000px;  
}
.cube {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform: rotate3d(1, 1, 1, 45deg); 
}
.side {
  position: absolute;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid green;
  font: normal 40px Arial;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 300px;
  color: #c8d6e5;
  
}
.front {
  transform: translateZ(150px);
}
.back {
  transform:  rotateY(180deg) translateZ(150px);
}
.right {
  transform: rotateY(90deg) translateZ(150px);
  background-color: #feca57;
}
.left {
  transform: rotateY(-90deg) translateZ(150px);
  background-color: #ff6b6b;  
  
}
.top {
  transform: rotateX(90deg) translateZ(150px);
  background-color: #48dbfb;
}
.bottom {
  transform: rotateX(-90deg) translateZ(150px);
  background-color: #1dd1a1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
   <div class="cube">
        <div class="side front"></div>
        <div class="side back"></div>
        <div class="side right">We are cool</div>
        <div class="side left">We are mazing</div>
        <div class="side top">We are super</div>
        <div class="side bottom">We are creative</div>
   </div>
</div>
```

[Лежит давненько на моём заброшенном Codepen](https://codepen.io/LFC_Red/pen/eRXJGM)

Далее разные вариации на тему:

[Вертикальный трёхмерный куб-слайдер (без JS)](https://codepen.io/vavik96/pen/Pwryzr)

[Горизонтальный трёхмерный куб-слайдер (без JS)](https://codepen.io/vavik96/pen/XJLxXa)

Также, [вот этот вариант интересный](https://codepen.io/desandro/pen/KRWjzm)

[На CSS-tricks хорошо разобрали процесс создания куба](https://css-tricks.com/simplifying-css-cubes-custom-properties/)

Comment: Открой на полный экран, он не адаптивный, тогда я про это не думал, да и задачи такой не стояло. Вращается вроде так как тебе надо